# include function partially not working w/o modifications

Tags: php

**BACKGROUND**
Recently we upgraded our web server (PHP 5.3.3) by replacing it with a new server (PHP 5.3.3) and at least one of the include functions stopped working.

Following a response on this site I changed the include function from "include('requested_page');" to "getcwd()."/".$_SESSION['requested_page'];" and that fixed the issue.

getcwd() returns "var/lib/vhost/httpdocs/

**QUESTION**

Is there a setting in php.ini (or else where) that needs to be changed to allow the include function to work w/o adding getcwd()?

**INFO:**
Old server: Centos 5, new server Centos 6, both servers are running PHP 5.3.3 and Plesk 11

Thanks

Comment: This most likely belongs on [server fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Comment: @nickb: Not really. `include_path` is a fairly common thing to change, even for programmers.

Comment: @Leigh - The question is still about server upgrades and configurations, and the problem stems from server changes, hence the vote for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive for setting the directory for looking for included files.

> Specifies a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(),
>   file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files.
>   The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a list of
>   directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows.
>
> PHP considers each entry in the include path separately when looking
>   for files to include. It will check the first path, and if it doesn't
>   find it, check the next path, until it either locates the included
>   file or returns with a warning or an error. You may modify or set your
>   include path at runtime using set_include_path().